# Unable to find vcvarsall.bat(while installing scikit-image: pip)

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install pylab in windows python
But half-way down while installing scikit-image I got the error-message:

> Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

I tried to fix it by installing Visual C++ compiler package but it did not fix it
Please suggest any probable solution to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can download a wheel of `scikit-image` from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-image) which allows you bypass installation with `vcvarsall.bat`. Install by doing:

```
 pip install scikit_image-*.whl
```

Be sure to select a version that matches your python installation and system architecture.

Comment: I downloaded the scikit-image in zip file but I don't know where to save it and when I try to run the suggested command it is giving me an error:         Requirement 'scikit_image-*.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
scikit_image-*.whl is not a valid wheel filename.

Answer (score 0):

Here, .whl files are wheel packages. Any packages that can be installed using 'pip' can be found as wheel packages and can be installed independently.

Type in terminal

```
python --version
```

to check the Python version and architecture .

So Confirm your version and rest of details and Download the package from : 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-image

Then,

```
pip install "YOUR_WHEEL_PACKAGE_NAME".whl
```

This should bypass your issues on pip installation of scikit-image.